# How to append 2 items in a d3 v4 force layout that updates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 v4 force layout and currently in my updateForceLayout function that I call when I add or remove a node I have this:

```
 // Add and remove message nodes
const join = d3
    .select(".container")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data);

// Remove old groups
join
  .exit()
  .remove();

// Create the new groups
const groups = join
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "outer");


// Merge the new groups with the existing groups
// and apply an appropriate translation
const innerJoin = groups
    .merge(join)
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
  .selectAll(".inner")
  .data(d => d.m);

// Remove old ones
innerJoin
    .exit()
  .remove()


  let  newCircles = innerJoin
     .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr("class", "innerbox")
   .attr("y", (d,i) => {
     return -65 - (i * 15)
   })
   .attr("width", 70)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .style("fill", "green")


   newCircles.merge(join)
```

This is a nested selection so it's a bit more complex but the problem is simple and only lies in the last part. I want to be able to add text and a rect to "newCircles", but can only add one or the other. When I try this at the end instead:

```
  let  newCircles = innerJoin
     .enter()
   .append('g')



     newCircles
      .append('rect')
      .attr("class", "innerbox")
      .attr("y", (d,i) => {
        return -65 - (i * 15)
      })
      .attr("width", 70)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", "green")

      newCircles
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "innertext")
        .text(function(d){return d})
        .attr("y", (d,i) => {
          return -55 - (i * 15)
        })
        .style("white-space", "pre");
```

My force layout bugs out and one of the nodes jumps off of the screen when I update the nodes. I am assuming I am not adding or removing or merging correctly now that I have a group with 2 elements inside and not just 1 element. What is the correct way to achieve this?